# I cannot access javascript object array property contents populated by callback that are visible in developer tools

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object, jquery-callback

Within a Javascript object (`testObject`) I am populating an array with objects from a `jQuery.getJSON` callback function. The array is defined first as an object property `this.publicArray` and `var passedArray = this` enables the inner callback function to access the public object.

Using a public method to the object i can expose the contents of the populated array as a child property of the object, but not the contents of the array directly.

```
function testObject() {

  this.publicArray = [];
  var passedArray = this;

  $.getJSON('http://...',
    function(data) {
      passedArray.publicArray = [{key:'value'},{key:'value'},{key:'value'}]  
  });

  this.testMethod = function() {
    console.log(this);
    console.log(this.publicArray);
  };
}

myObject = new testObject(); // [1]
myObject.testMethod(); // [2]
```

returns:

```
 [1] > thisArray: Array[3]
         0: Object
           key: "value"
         1: Object
           key: "value"
         2: Object
           key: "value"
         length: 3

 [2] > []
```

If i populate the array with exact same objects but not from a callback function it behaves as I expect it to, so I don't understand:

1. How to access the contents of the array from the object method
2. Why the array contents are visible to Developer Tools and not to my script.

Thanks - and please do feel free to educate me on anything else i have screwed up.

Comment: Ajax is asynchronous. the callback happens a period of time after the new instance is created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues with what you are trying to do.

For one, when you create the new instance of 'testObject' you are making an ajax request to populate the array property 'itsArray'. This property will have it's default value ([]) until the ajax request is complete.

Because AJAX is asynchronous by default (meaning the code will execute your 'getJSON' call and continue to the next statement immediately), any calls to 'testMethod' will return an empty array until the ajax request is complete.

What you can do is use the 'promise' that an ajax request returns ([Jquery Deferred Objects](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/)) and wait for the promise to be resolved, like so:

```
function testObject() {

  this.itsArray = [];
  var passedArray = this;

  this.getJSONPromise = $.getJSON('http://...',
    function(data) {
      passedArray.itsArray = [{key:'value'},{key:'value'},{key:'value'}]  
  });

  this.testMethod = function() {
    console.log(this);
    console.log(this.itsArray);
  };
}
```

Now that we have a 'promise' object to work with, we can wait for it to complete to call the testMethod and we will have our data.

```
myObject = new testObject();
$.when(myObject.getJSONPromise).then(function()
{
    myObject.testMethod();
});
```

Comment: Since you are only dealing with one promise object, you could also do `myObject.getJSONPromise.done(function(){...});`

Comment: so that would be some implicit onReady as per KevinB's answer but gifted by jQuery?

Comment: KevinB's answer masks the jQuery promise object (var request), while mine exposes it. It's 6 one way half-dozen the other. The promise object is immutable so it's not an issue to expose it as a property on the testObject.

Comment: i got the 6:6 impression. i think the promise route may lead to more compact (less likely to forget things) when looking at it as a pattern learned for next time

Answer (score 1):

Ajax is asynchronous. the callback happens a period of time after the new instance is created.

Try something like this. When the data is ready to be manipulated, the onReady callback will happen (not tested):

```
function testObject() {

    this.itsArray = [];
    var passedArray = this;

    var request = $.getJSON('http://...', function(data) {
        passedArray.itsArray = [
            {
            key: 'value'},
        {
            key: 'value'},
        {
            key: 'value'}
        ];
    });

    this.testMethod = function() {
        console.log(this);
        console.log(this.itsArray);
    };
    this.onReady = function(fn) {
        request.done(fn)
    };
}

var myObject = new testObject(); // [1]
// the following can be used multiple times
myObject.onReady(function() {
    myObject.testMethod(); // [2]
});​
```